# communication between flex modules by interfaces

Tags: apache-flex, types, casting, module

I have defined 3 interfaces in my flex project, "B", "C" and "D". The "D" interface extends the "B" interface, and the "C" interface is a consumer of the "B" type instance. After that, I have defined 2 modules, M1 and M2. M1 implements the "D" interface and M2 implements the "C" interface. M2 has a public function as following.

```
/* in the "M2" module */
// the stub is declared in the "C" interface.
public function consume(b:B):void{ 
    if(b is D){                  // line 1: type determination
        // do something on the D interface
    }
}
```

And then I defined 2 module loaders (mld1 & mld2) to load M1 and M2 (by setting the url) in the main application. And after M1 and M2 are both loaded, I tried to provide M1 for M2 via the "C.consume(B):void" function implemented in the M2 module. Codes are like the following.

```
/* in the "main" application */
var m1:B = mld1.child as B;      // line 2: cast type to B
var m2:C = mld2.child as C;
m2.consume(m1);                  // line 3: provide m1 instance for m2
```

However, when it calls the M2.consume(B):void function in line 3, the "if" determination in the consume function (line 1) will always fail and the body of the "if" structure will always be skipped. But if I add the type determination line as shown in line 1 in the "M2" module to the main application before line 3, then the type determination in line 1 will be successful. That's to say the codes as the following in the main application will make it possible to pass the type determination in line 1.

```
 /* in the "main" application: make type determination be line 3 */
var m1:B = mld1.child as B;     // line 2: cast type to B
if(m1 is D)                     // just make a plain determination. nothing else.
    ;                            
var m2:C = mld2.child as C;
m2.consume(m1);                 // line 3: provide m1 instance for m2
```

or if I make a type cast directly to the D type, it will also reach the same result.

```
/* in the "main" application: make type cast before line 3 */
var m1:B = mld1.child as D;     // line 2: after modified, cast type to D.
var m2:C = mld2.child as C;
m2.consume(m1);                 // line 3: provide m1 instance for m2
```

I just wonder why the determination in line 1 will be successful only if I have mentioned the "D" type in the main application. Will the type determination or type cast in the main application make any difference on the target object? And what should I do, if I wish the main application to be aware of just the "B" interface and its consumer interface (the "C" interface), so that the application can support any sub interfaces and classes of the "B" and "C" interface.

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing personal, but my simple mind is confused by all of this alphabet soup :) I think your explanation would be more clear if you showed variable names that had meaning. Going to give it another read over...

Comment: @Sunil D. Thank you for your advice. I appreciate it very much. In fact, I have tried to name them in a meanful way, "B" for Base interface, "C" for Consumer interface and "D" for Derived interface. They just take the first letter as their id. Well, maybe I didn't point this out clear.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to follow everything you have written, so may be I missed something, but If you don't import D into the main application, it will not get compiled into the resulting SWF. This is why the main application will not be aware of D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I expect the main application to be unaware of D, and the 2 modules loaded by the main application to be aware of it. What the main application cares about is that it should get a B type object and a C type consumer which can consume the B type object, and then it will hand the B object to the C type consumer with the C.consume(B) function. As we know, we can have many implementations for an interface. The main application will not care about whether the B type object is also a D type instance or not. Who should care about it is the concrete modules.

Comment: The length limit! Well, I wish the main application to be a general application for all implementations of any B instance and any C instance. If only I loaded any 2 modules (implemented the B & C interface respectively), and set the relationship with the consume function, then they will be able to run right. So the main application should not mention the D interface and the concrete implementation M1 and M2, and of course, they should be compiled into the resulting SWF of the main application. Otherwise, the main application won't be as general as expected.